# Is there a way to do a "mass delete" of unused pages and pictures in Mediawiki. The deleteArchivedFiles.php is not working as expected

Tags: mediawiki

Mediawiki Version: 1.34

PHP Version: 7.3

Database Type: 10.3.24-MariaDB - MariaDB Server

Is there a way to do a "mass delete" of unused pages and pictures. The deleteArchivedFiles.php is not working as expected.

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "unused"?

Comment: There are unused files present in special pages which i want to bulk delete. Also i want to pages that are archived

Answer (score 1):

To get the list of unused files, use *MediaWiki* API:

https://mediawiki.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&list=querypage&qppage=Unusedimages&qplimit=500&qpoffset=0.

This URL will fetch 500 records (`qplimit`) for unused files (`qppage`) from mediawiki.org (replace with your project) starting from 0 (`qpoffset`) in JSON format (`format`). XML is also available.

You can use `jq` (`apt install jq`) to parse JSON and extract full titles of file pages:

```sh
wget -cq -O - 'https://mediawiki.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&list=querypage&qppage=Unusedimages&qplimit=500&qpoffset=0' | jq -r '.query.querypage.results[].title' >> list.txt
```

Or, you can simply `grep`:

```sh
wget -cq -O - 'https://mediawiki.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&list=querypage&qppage=Unusedimages&qplimit=500&qpoffset=0' | grep -oP '(?<="title":")[^"]+' >> list.txt
```

You may need to repeat this increasing `qpoffset` by `qplimit` until there is nothing left in `.query.querypage.results`.

Assuming that you have collected the list of what you want to delete in the file `list.txt`, one entry per line, use the maintenance script `php maintenance/deleteBatch.php -u "deleting user" -r "reason for deletion" list.txt`.

Further reading:

- https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Querypage#Special_page_values
- https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/
- https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:DeleteBatch.php.

Comment: I want to collect a list first, how do i do that

Comment: @dsouzajoel22, I don't understand what are "pages that are archived". For unused files, see the updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for @Alexander Mashin. I used the same script to get an unused image list but I couldn't delete the image because I got the non-exist page error when I run the delete batch script. So, I installed https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:DeleteBatch extension and open Special:DeleteBatch page and paste the file list. Your images/deleted folder should have correct file permission otherwise, it cannot delete the files.